# Why is my function returning 0.0? (C code)

Tags: c

I've got a function that calculates the magnitude of a vector with a user specified size (dimension)

```
float VectorMagnitude(int vectorA[], int sizeVector)
{
    float total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeVector; i++) {
        total = total + (vectorA[i] * vectorA[i]);
    }
    total = sqrt(total);
    return total;
}
```

if I print the result

```
printf("Magnitude of vector = %.2f\n", VectorMagnitude(Vec, size));
```

If I run the debugger with `vectorA = {7, 5, 7}` (with size being 3 obviously), the value of `total` just before I return it is 11.09... (which is correct).

However, the printed value is 0.0.

What am I doing wrong? (Its for a uni project so the random values are just fillers, I dont need to use actual values yet)

**FULL CODE**
***main.c***

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "matrixOperations.h"

int main()
{
int size;
 printf("Enter size of vector:\n");
 scanf("%d",&size);
int Vec[size];
FillMatrix(Vec,1,size);
DisplayMatrix(Vec,1,size);
printf("Magnitude of vector = %.2f\n",VectorMagnitude(Vec,size));




    return 0;
}
```

***matrixOperations.c***

```
#include "matrixOperations.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

/////////////////////////////////
 void DisplayMatrix(int matrix[], int sizeRow, int sizeCol)
 { printf("Print matrix:\n");
    for (int i=0;i<sizeRow;i++)
        {
            for (int j=0;j<sizeCol;j++)
                {
                    printf("%d ", matrix[i*sizeCol+j]);
                }
                 printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n");
 }
////////////////////////////////////////////////
void FillMatrix(int matrix[], int sizeRow, int sizeCol)
 {
    srand(time(0));
    for (int i=0;i<sizeRow;i++)
        {
            for (int j=0;j<sizeCol;j++)
                {
                    matrix[i*sizeCol+j]=rand()%10;
                }
        }
 }


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 float VectorMagnitude(int vectorA[], int sizeVector)
 {
 float total=0;
 for (int i=0;i<sizeVector;i++)
    {
     total=total+ (vectorA[i]*vectorA[i]);
    }
    total = sqrt(total);
 return total;
 }
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

***matrixOperations.h***

```
#ifndef MATRIXOPERATIONS_H_INCLUDED
#define MATRIXOPERATIONS_H_INCLUDED



#endif // MATRIXOPERATIONS_H_INCLUDED
```

Comment: Can you show us the full program? I cannot reproduce it when picking all infos together: https://godbolt.org/z/E6M6eEErj

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://ideone.com/oVlTn0

Comment: Your code is fine, the problem is elsewhere in the code you didn't show. [Edit] and show a [mcve]. What is your platform?

Comment: I've added the full code

Comment: @SenorGeraldo Provide a minimal complete program that demonstrates the problem instead of your full code

Comment: Ive edited the full code

Comment: A [mcve] should include the input that triggers the problem. Also compile with all warnings enabled.

Comment: What's in `"matrixOperations.h"`?

Comment: `size` in `main` is not declared. `#include <time.h>` is missing in matrixOperation.c. But then it works if you have the correct prototypes in the header file: https://godbolt.org/z/96T3W4zhx

Comment: Can you show how you declared the ```size``` variable ?

Comment: The problem here is that `matrixOperations.h` doesn't contain anything useful. It should contain the function prototypes of the functions in `matrixOperations.c`: Like `void DisplayMatrix(int matrix[], int sizeRow, int sizeCol);
void FillMatrix(int matrix[], int sizeRow, int sizeCol); etc.`

Comment: @Jabberwocky aah thank you. Our lecturer didn't really explain how to use multiple .c files

Comment: @SenorGeraldo ... the deleted answer is actually quit a correct.

Comment: Didn't you get some warnings from your compiler about implicitely declaring functions when you call them without a prototype?

Comment: @SenorGeraldo whenever you see a compiler diagnostic containing the word _"implicit"_, consider it as a serious error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing `#include "matrixOperations.h"` in main.c ... err ... I mean: you're missing having a valid prototype in scope for the function (in the absence of a prototype C assumes the function accepts `int` arguments and returns `int` values)

Comment: Hi, sorry the code in the question wasn't copied properly

Comment: The "matrixOperations.h" does **NOT** include a prototype for the function. My nswer is still valid after your latest edit.